# Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3, closures, implicit

I'm learning swift from Apple iBook when I was going through closures part (page 128), there is one implicit Returns example when I ran that example in my PG that was showing some error

> Playground execution failed: error: 12.playground:248:45: error:
>   expected ',' separator let sorted = returnss.sorted(by: { ( s1, s2 in
>   return s1 < s2 })

I checked it twice. Here is my program:

```
var listForShort: [Int] = [4, 65, 343, 22, 5445, 343]

let sorted = listForShort.sorted(by: { ( s1, s2 in s1 < s2 })

for sort in sorted {
    print(sort)
}
```

version swift 3.1

Comment: There is not enough closing parenthesis in this statement

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
 let sorted2 = listForShort.sorted(by: { s1, s2 in s1 > s2 } )
```

Remove the extra brackets

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing bracket:

```
listForShort.sorted(by: { ( s1, s2) in s1 < s2 })
```

There is a nicer syntax you might want to checkout:

```
listForShort.sorted { $0 < $1 }
```

Comment: `{ $0 < $1 }` has the same type as `<`, so you can just use `.sorted(by: <)`. Furthermore, this is the default behaviour, so you can just call `.sorted()`.